# Problem with debugging firefox extension

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox-addon

I'm using Venkman javascript debugger for debugging firefox extension. I set a breakpoint, the javascript is running, but it won't stop on my breakpoints, so I can't debug.

Could you help me with this problem? What's wrong or advise me some alternative debugger?

thank you

Comment: Man you are so not alone in this. 2 years later and our options are still only Venkman or Chromebug. Both are unbelievably buggy and unreliable. Mozilla, if you're listening. Get us some better Chrome/XUL development tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  Much, much better than Venkman.

Comment: I have firebug installed but I can't find there my javascript code. It's in firefox extension.

Comment: Click the firebug icon, and then click on the Console tab.  There's a little arrow on there.  Click that, and make sure that everything starting with the word "Chrome" is checked.

Comment: Firebug is useless to debug extensions, it is meant for web pages. If anything, you would use Chromebug - but I don't know whether it really works better than Venkman (never used it).

Comment: @Wladimir Thank you. Stackexchange haven't notified me about your (this) comment, so I was even asking on Firebug and Chromebug was advised to me.

Comment: In recent versions of Firefox, Firebug has unfortunately become unbelievably slow - I imagine adding Chrome scope to it would make the browser even more unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes when you have Firebug *and* Venkman installed at the same time. Try disabling Firebug, not just from within Firebug's own menu but actually going to the addons list, disabling it, and restarting the browser.

Comment: The problem was here before firebug was installed.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the same file is loaded multiple times - e.g. you have several windows open and each of them loads utils.js. Each window loaded the same script but each of them has a different instance of this script now. For the debugger each instance of a script is different (technically speaking, in JavaScript they really are) and when you set a breakpoint you might be doing it on the wrong script instance.

Comment: I tried to close all tabs and leave only one tab open. But I can't find in Venkman my javascript code between loaded scripts. It's not there now. This is quite strange.

Comment: Venkman has problems showing scripts that were loaded before you opened Venkman. That might be the issue here.

Comment: I have a fuzzy feeling I heard about it but has this issue solution?

Comment: Sure it does - run Venkman when starting Firefox by adding `-venkman` to the command line. This makes sure that Venkman is loaded before any scripts (it also decreases performance significantly so you shouldn't do it when you are not debugging).

Comment: I tried it but still can't find my script between loaded scripts.